Task data structure is not as expected. Ensure each task is a tuple
I get the following error while running my python script;
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 175
173 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
174     for task_data in meta_train_loader:
--> 175         maml.train_step(task_data)
177 # Fine-tuning on new user data
178 new_user_data = torch.randn(1, 768)
Cell In[5], line 69, in MAML.train_step(self, task_data)
67     support_set, query_set = task
68 else:
---> 69     raise ValueError("Task data structure is not as expected. Ensure each task is a tuple of (support_set, query_set).")
71 # Ensure the sets are dictionaries
72 if not isinstance(support_set, dict) or not isinstance(query_set, dict):
ValueError: Task data structure is not as expected. Ensure each task is a tuple of (support_set, query_set).

The message is quite clear "Ensure each task is a tuple of (support_set, query_set)". I would look into that. Get your debugging session started, set a break point there and inspect your variables.
